# nodejs mongodb connection pooling problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I'm trying to use connection pooling in my node app, but it doesn't work as expected. Here is my code:

`db.js`

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import MongoClient from 'mongodb';

dotenv.config();

let db;

export async function getDb() {
  if (db) {
    console.log('reusing db connection');
    return db;
  }
  try {
    const conn = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.DEV_URI,
                                           { useUnifiedTopology: true,
                                             maxPoolSize: 5 });
    console.log('db connection created');
    db = conn.db('dev');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return db;
}
```

This is `app.js`.

```js
import { getDb } from './db.js';

async function foo() {
  const db = await getDb();
}

async function bar() {
  const db = await getDb();
}

// This outputs 8 lines of 'db connection created'
foo(); bar();
foo(); bar();
foo(); bar();
foo(); bar();
```

So running app.js, I expected only 5 connections created at max, but every foo() and bar() creates a new collection. How can I make each async operation can pick an idle connection in the pool?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it too fast :) All the async functions are executed at once, so when each one starts, there is no connection.

Try to add `await getDb();` before calling `foo(); bar();`.

Another solution would be to use some kind of mutex or semaphore in `getDb()`.

Comment: how does that make any difference? I think the first call foo() will call await getDb(); anyway?

Comment: Yes. And the first call `bar()` will also `await getDb()` at the same time. The second and third call of `bar()` will also `await getDb()` at the same time. Put there some debug console logs so you can see.

Comment: You would have to call `await foo()` and `await bar()` instead.